# Include list(s) in list

Tags: r

I'm trying to recreate the `tohave` list but using the `helpers` variable.
Knowing that **I don't know the length of helpers** variables.

```
# The list I want to create
tohave <- list(
    list(var1 = "A", var2 = 1),
    list(var1 = "B", var2 = 2),
    list(var1 = "C", var2 = 3),
    list(var1 = "D", var2 = 4),
    list(var1 = "E", var2 = 5),
    list(var1 = "F", var2 = 6),
    list(var1 = "G", var2 = 7),
    list(var1 = "H", var2 = 8),
    list(var1 = "I", var2 = 9),
    list(var1 = "J", var2 = 10)
)

# 'Helpers' variables I want to use to recreate tohave
helper1 <- list(
    list(var1 = "B", var2 = 2),
    list(var1 = "C", var2 = 3)
)

helper2 <- list(
    list(var1 = "H", var2 = 8),
    list(var1 = "I", var2 = 9)
)

tohave2 <- list(
    list(var1 = "A", var2 = 1),
    helper1,
    list(var1 = "D", var2 = 4),
    list(var1 = "E", var2 = 5),
    list(var1 = "F", var2 = 6),
    list(var1 = "G", var2 = 7),
    helper2,
    list(var1 = "J", var2 = 10)
)
```

At the end I need to recreate exactly the `tohave` variable

Comment: Friendly tip for more readable code
            *Do not place a space before a comma, but always place one after a
            comma.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can wrap the other lists into lists so they match the form of the helpers, then use `?c`.

```
tohave2 <- c(
    list(list(var1 = "A", var2 = 1)),
    helper1,
    list(
        list(var1 = "D", var2 = 4),
        list(var1 = "E", var2 = 5),
        list(var1 = "F", var2 = 6),
        list(var1 = "G", var2 = 7)
    ),
    helper2,
    list(list(var1 = "J", var2 = 10))
    )

identical(tohave, tohave2)

#[1] TRUE
```

Comment: actually you don't have to use `tohave`. I was about to post kind of similar answer but I think you have got it covered.

Comment: Thanks for reply, But what I want at the end is `identical(ans, tohave)`. I edited my question to be more clear

Answer (score 2):

A third option using `append`

```
tohave2 <- append(x = tohave2, values = helper1, after = 1)
tohave2 <- append(x = tohave2, values = helper2, after = 7)
identical(tohave, tohave2)
#[1] TRUE
```

**data**

```
tohave <- list(
  list(var1 = "A", var2 = 1),
  list(var1 = "B", var2 = 2),
  list(var1 = "C", var2 = 3),
  list(var1 = "D", var2 = 4),
  list(var1 = "E", var2 = 5),
  list(var1 = "F", var2 = 6),
  list(var1 = "G", var2 = 7),
  list(var1 = "H", var2 = 8),
  list(var1 = "I", var2 = 9),
  list(var1 = "J", var2 = 10)
)

# 'Helpers' variables I want to use to recreate tohave
helper1 <- list(
  list(var1 = "B", var2 = 2),
  list(var1 = "C", var2 = 3)
)

helper2 <- list(
  list(var1 = "H", var2 = 8),
  list(var1 = "I", var2 = 9)
)

tohave2 <- list(
  list(var1 = "A", var2 = 1),
  # helper1,
  list(var1 = "D", var2 = 4),
  list(var1 = "E", var2 = 5),
  list(var1 = "F", var2 = 6),
  list(var1 = "G", var2 = 7),
  # helper2,
  list(var1 = "J", var2 = 10)
)
```

Comment: Thanks markus, that's good ! Would you have an idea if I have several `helpers`. (I'm sorry I edited my question before I saw your answer)

Comment: @qfazille You can just append as many times as you have helpers.

Comment: @qfazille Call `append` twice. If you need to do it more than two times you could write a little function that does the appending for you.

Comment: I switch accepted answer to @Andre Elrico one because his solution is more convenient when we don't know the length of `helpers` list